# Crear un botón que al presionarlo indique en qué posición del array de su padre se encuentra con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

en HTML tengo un nav con 5 elementos hijos

```
<nav class="textoNav">
   <a href="#" class="botonSobreMi">Sobre mi</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonHabilidades">Habilidades</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonExperiencia">Experiencia</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonPortafolio">Portafolio</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonContacto">Contacto</a>
</nav>
```

En JavaScript tengo un addEventListener para saber en cual de los elementos se ha hecho click, mi problema surge al intentar obtener el número de la posición de los "a" en el array del elemento padre textoNav, por ejemplo, si presiono en botonSobreMi que me devuelva la posición 0, o en botonPortafolio que me devuelva la posición 3, adjunto lo que tengo en JS.

```
const navSeleccionado = document.querySelectorAll(".textoNav>a");
console.log(navSeleccionado);

navSeleccionado.forEach((elementoHijo) => {

    elementoHijo.addEventListener('click', () => {

    console.log(elementoHijo);

    })
});
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, lamento si no he sido claro con mi duda, es mi primera pregunta en esta página y soy nuevo en la programación, que tengan un buen día.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, basta usar un segundo argumento en la función que usas en el método [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) de tu lista de nodos seleccionados:

```js
nodeList.forEach((childNode, index) => { ... }
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const navSeleccionado = document.querySelectorAll(".textoNav>a");

navSeleccionado.forEach((elementoHijo, index) => {

    elementoHijo.addEventListener('click', () => {

    console.log('Elemento seleccionado:', index);

    })
});
```

```html
<nav class="textoNav">
   <a href="#" class="botonSobreMi">Sobre mi</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonHabilidades">Habilidades</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonExperiencia">Experiencia</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonPortafolio">Portafolio</a>
   <a href="#" class="botonContacto">Contacto</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un ciclo `for` para recorrer a los elementos que colecciona `querySelectorAll()`, y dentro del `for` usas el listener para cada posición del elemento (que son tus etiquetas `<a>`), y cuando hagas clic en uno de ellos, escuchará el evento clic y ejecuta la instrucción, quien se encarga de capturar el índice donde se encuentra ese elemento quien escuchó el evento del clic.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
const navSeleccionado = document.querySelectorAll(".textoNav>a");
// console.log(navSeleccionado);

for (let i = 0; i < navSeleccionado.length; i++) {
  navSeleccionado[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("La posición es: " + i);
  });
}
```

```html
<nav class="textoNav">
  <a href="#" class="botonSobreMi">Sobre mi</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonHabilidades">Habilidades</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonExperiencia">Experiencia</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonPortafolio">Portafolio</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonContacto">Contacto</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

En *javascript*, un objeto puede tener propiedades de clave y valor.

En este caso, puede usar el operador  [**spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  `...` para crear copias de elementos de NodeList en una matriz, convierte `NodeList` en una matriz.

El [**Object.entries(**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) sirve para iterar estos elementos por clave y valor

```js
for (const [index, link] of Object.entries([...document.querySelectorAll(".textoNav>a")])){
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("posición: " + index);
  });
}
```

```html
<nav class="textoNav">
  <a href="#" class="botonSobreMi">Sobre mi</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonHabilidades">Habilidades</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonExperiencia">Experiencia</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonPortafolio">Portafolio</a>
  <a href="#" class="botonContacto">Contacto</a>
</nav>
```